# What is the correct way of using letters in for loops?

Tags: c++, for-loop, ascii, nested-loops, password-generator

When I start debugging nothing is being printed, I'm not even sure what that means, I think the mistake is probably in the 3rd and 4th for loops, for the alphabetic ASCII characters, because I'm not sure if this is the correct way of writing them.

I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Write a program that reads two integers n and l entered by the user and generate in alphabetical order
> all possible passwords, which consist of the following 5 characters:
> Symbol 1 : i, digit from 1 to n.
> Symbol 2 : j, digit from 1 to n.
> Symbol 3 : letter, lowercase letter among the first l letters of the Latin alphabet.
> Symbol 4 : secondletter, lowercase letter among the first l letters of the Latin alphabet.
> Symbol 5 : d, digit from 1 to n, greater than the first 2 digits.
> The input is read from the console and consists of two integers n and l in the interval[1… 9], one per line.
> All passwords must be printed alphabetically on the console, separated by a space.

```
My code: 
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int l = 0;
    cout << "Input n (1, 9): " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    while (n < 1 || n > 9)
    {
        cout << "Input n (1, 9): " << endl;
        cin >> n;
    }
    cout << "Input l (1, 9): " << endl;
    cin >> l;
    while (l < 1 || l > 9)
    {
        cout << "Input l (1, 9): " << endl;
        cin >> l;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            for (char letter = char(97); letter <= l; letter++)
            {
                for (char secondletter = char(97); secondletter <= l; secondletter++)
                {
                    for (int d = 1; d <= n; d++)
                    {
                        if (d>i&&d>j)
                        {
                            cout << "Possible combination {1}{2}{3}{4}{5}: " << i << j << letter << secondletter << d << "\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char letter = char(97); letter <= l` if `l` is between 1 and 9, when do you ever expect this loop condition to evaluate to `true`?

Comment: The idea is to use the number encoding of the characters, I just don't know how to do that. If l is for example 3. I want a, b and c to be printed. Isn't it possible in that way?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to do:

```
for (char letter = char(97); letter <= (97+l); letter++)
            {
                for (char secondletter = char(97); secondletter <= (97+l); secondletter++)
                {
```

I didn't fully go through your code but this was quite straight forward to see that `letter <= (97+l)` is want you wanted in place of `letter <= l` and similarly for the other case.

One of the good practice is that to do something like:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 0;
    int l = 0;
    cout << "Input n (1, 9): " << endl;
    cin >> n;
    while (n < 1 || n > 9)
    {
        cout << "Input n (1, 9): " << endl;
        cin >> n;
    }
    cout << "Input l (1, 9): " << endl;
    cin >> l;
    while (l < 1 || l > 9)
    {
        cout << "Input l (1, 9): " << endl;
        cin >> l;
    }

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 1; j <= n; j++)
        {
            for (char letter = 'a'; letter <= 'a'+l; letter++)
            {
                for (char secondletter = 'a'; secondletter <= 'a'+l; secondletter++)
                {
                    for (int d = 1; d <= n; d++)
                    {
                        if (d>i&&d>j)
                        {
                            cout << "Possible combination {1}{2}{3}{4}{5}: " << i << j << letter << secondletter << d << "\n";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The idea is quite simple, `'a'=>97, 'a'+1=>98=>'b'` and it goes like that...

Comment: @JohnnyMopp just updating my answer while writing this